# How to close first form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have 2 forms in my project. Users cannot exit from the first from, frmOptometry. I have this implemented this way:

```
  Private Sub frmOptometry_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    MessageBox.Show("You can only close the application from the receipt screen!")
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

The second form, frmReceipt can be exited from. I have it implemented this way:

```
    Private Sub frmReceipt_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?",
                       "Obi-Wan Optometry Closing",
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) =
                   DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        frmOptometry.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Right now, it does not close the program completely because it goes to the frmOptometry_FormClosing and prevents it. What should I do to fix this? Is there anyway to figure out where the user is trying to shut down the program and then decide from there?

Comment: You could change the app to close when the last form closes.  There is also no need to ask "Are you sure you want to quit?" especially with an EXCLAMATION! -  that comes from a time when it took 4-7 minutes to load Lotus 1-2-3 from 5inch floppies.  If your app takes that long to load, refactor it

Comment: He didn't ask about Lotus... Also saying he doesn't need to ask if user wants to quit is quite irrelevant here... Just a few thoughts as none of what you mention pertain to his direct issue...

Comment: @Codexer: Providing guidance via the comments is quite appropriate.  As this particular guidance didn't address the users question its not provided as an answer.

Comment: Well there is no reason to force users to end the app only from the special form you chose to be the main form.  All that chatter can be gotten rid of if the app ends when the last form closes *or* start the app from Sub Main and manually end it with `Application.Exit`.  Better?

Comment: I wasn't saying explain yourself. But thanks for the information I'm sure OP will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is by introducing a `flag` (say, called `FromReceipt`) which indicates who asks the `frmOptometry` to close itself.

Something like this on `frmOptometry` will do:

```
Public FromReceipt As Boolean = False 'Add this
Private Sub frmOptometry_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If Not FromReceipt Then 'add this condition
        MessageBox.Show("You can only close the application from the receipt screen!")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And then on the `frmReceipt`:

```
Private Sub frmReceipt_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?",
                       "Obi-Wan Optometry Closing",
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) =
                   DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        frmOptometry.FromReceipt = True 'Add this line to tell the frmOptometry: this time you can really close it
        frmOptometry.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I did manage to solve the issue and ended up thinking to use a flag before you answered. I got busy and didn't get back on here until just now. (Oops :/ ) I appreciate your answer!